# I have confusion regarding Cloud Storage pricing plans

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

For Cloud Storage pricing, does 'GB transferred' also counts for the amount of data uploaded?

[image: I am talking about this]

Comment: Hm, that is not really a programming related question...

Comment: @WarrenFaith I am sorry I am new.Where should i upload this question?Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I would go directly to the official firebase mailing list/group: https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk?pli=1 There is even a [slack channel](https://firebase.community/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The billing for Cloud Storage bandwidth is based on egress (downloads), not ingress.  You can get more detailed information on the [Cloud Storage pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).  In particular you will want to understand the second on [network costs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing).

Comment: *firebaser here* That should indeed be "GB Downloaded", the same as the table above the calculator calls it. I just filed a bug to get the table and calculator to use the same term for it.